# How to specify path of kernel headers for non-kernel app in c?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, header-files, kernel-module

I need to transfer `fixp_t` typed number (defined at `<linux/fixp-arith.h>`, originally `s16`) from kernel module to client app using `ioctl`. Data types are very important, if variable size will differ - results can be very dangerous.

If i include `<linux/fixp-arith.h>` in both kernel and client app source code, client app fails to compile, because it can't find linux headers.

From other hand, `gcc -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/include/ app.c -o app` does not work, because `<linux/types.h>` re-defines existing types and compilation fails.

From other hand, i am scared to specify any data type by myself, because on every arch `s16`, and so `fixp_t` may be different.

How is it possible to workaround this?

Comment: The fixp_t data type was [removed in 4.1](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/559addc25b00ff3a40eff03a0b3873c2b6d726f8#diff-216d3531bf045f21c800ad587de56eb4), so you're probably going to have issues trying to use the data type in future. You're better off using your own data type to guarantee the transfer as **it's your ioctl**. (the return type was widened to s32)

Comment: @Petesh ok, but how i should deal with kernel functions, that return `s16` (before 4.1) and `s32` after? I could convert it perhaps.. but i dont know what type will give me kernel then...

Comment: Kernel modules know because are compiled against kernel headers. So conversion is not a problem.

Comment: @Frankie_C but i have to call some specific function.. Imagine i have in my `ioctl` transport struct `long int`. In 3.16 kernel i get s16 result, and what will happen if i will try to write it to 32-byte integer? I mean i have to make some conversions by myself.

Comment: @Frankie_C got it. Function names are different. If you will add this as an answer, i will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your own `ioctl` using what you want.
The specific header will be crafted so that can be included in both app and kernel.
Kernel modules, compiled against kernel headers, will do the correct conversion.

Answer (score 3):

From the gcc man page:

> `-I dir`
>     Add the directory dir to the list of directories to be searched for header files.

So, to add the directory you would use:

```
-I /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/include/
```

However, I don't think user space programs are supposed to include kernel headers. If your kernel module has a user space API, then that API should be declared in a header that is separate from the kernel headers and that relies only on standard header files.

Comment: I am exchangin data with kernel using ioctl, and data type is very important because it's size should match. In kernel module i use `s16` or more specific `fixp_t`.

Comment: `-I` parameter did not work for me, because somehow `linux/types.h` tries to re-define types again :(

Comment: Which type to us is a design decision. You should either use a type that is an exact match or a type that is sufficiently large (and then cast/convert it to `fixp_t` inside your module.